# If $I \subseteq A$ such that all finitely generated module satisfies $IM=M$ implies $M=0$ then prove that $I \subseteq J$, Jacobson radical

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

> If $I \subseteq A$ such that all finitely generated $A$ module satisfies $IM=M$ implies $M=0$ then prove that $I \subseteq J$, Jacobson radical of $A$.

I didn't get any clue how to start with.

May be one approach would be to take $M=A$ but we know $IA=I$ so it will not work.

So what about $M=A/m$ where $m$ is a maximal ideal then $I(A/m)=\sum_{finite} i_j(a_j+m)=i_ja_j+m$. So what about this? Now guide me from here.

Moreover, my intuition of choosing $A/m$ was that I have to show $I \subseteq J$ Jacobson radical so somehow I have to bring maximal ideals into play.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $S$ be any simple left $A$ module. Obviously it is nonzero and finitely generated.

$IS$ is a submodule of $S$, so it is either $S$ or $\{0\}$. But $IS\neq S$ since $S\neq \{0\}$. Therefore $I$ annihilates $S$. This is true for every simple left $A$ module, so $I\subseteq J(A)$.

This has a very direct translation to maximal left ideals, if you'd prefer that. Ask questions if you get stuck.

Comment: This argument is simple and also works for noncommutative rings

Comment: Perhaps easier: if $I\not\subseteq J$, then there is a simple module $S$ such that $IS\ne\{0\}$ (implying $IS=S$).

Answer (score 2):

Let $M$ be a maximal ideal of $A$, $A/M$ is a field, if $I(A/M)\neq 0$ it implies that there exists an element $i$ of $I$ whose image in $A/M$ by the canonical projection $p:A\rightarrow A/M$is not zero, thus $p(i)$ is invertible and for every $a\in A$, $p(a)=p(i)({p(i)}^{-1}p(a))$ it implies that $I(A/M)=A/M$ and $A/M=0$ contradiction since $M\neq A$. We deduce that $I(A/M)=0$ and henceforth, $I\subset M$, we deduce that $I\subset Jac(A)$.